# Transfer large Datasets to Azure blob storage from Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azcopy, multipart-upload

I want to transfer large datasets from Amazon s3 to Azure Blob storage. Can anyone help me with how can I modify my code to handle large datasets? Below is my code in java:

```
        try {
            storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(azureCredentialsDto.getStorageAccountName(), azureCredentialsDto.getStorageAccountKey()), true);
            blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            container = blobClient.getContainerReference(azureCredentialsDto.getBlobContainerName());

            log.info("Creating Container: "+container.getName());
            container.createIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER, new BlobRequestOptions(), new OperationContext());
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(destinationFileName);
            URI blockbloburl = blob.getUri();
            log.info("Blob URI: " + blockbloburl);
           // sourcefileurl is url of amazons3 file I want to copy
            blob.startCopy(new URI(sourceFileUrl));
            log.info("Copy Started...");
```

Comment: What do you mean by large datasets? Do you mean large number of files that you want to transfer or large sized file?

Comment: @GauravMantri I mean large sized file like 23GB. Is there any file size limit for blob.startCopy()?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have referred your article for this and I have also tested that 23GB file was copied successfully from s3 to Azure Blob storage. But I can't find any documentation on the size limit of this "Copy blob". I want to confirm this with documentation so that there is no impact on performance in the future.
 https://dzone.com/articles/how-copy-amazon-s3-bucket

Comment: I don't think there is any limit on the size of the file that can be copied. The limitations of copy operations are mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob#remarks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to transfer the files with large size the best option is to use `Copy activity` in **Azure Data Factory (ADF)**.

> AzCopy is a command-line utility that you can use to copy blobs or
> files to or from a storage account. AzCopy v10 (Preview) now supports
> Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3 as a data source. You can now copy an
> entire AWS S3 bucket, or even multiple buckets, to Azure Blob Storage
> using AzCopy.

AzCopy and ADF are the two best approach when we need to move large size files.

To use AzCopy refer [Move your data from AWS S3 to Azure Storage using AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/move-your-data-from-aws-s3-to-azure-storage-using-azcopy/)

To accomplish it using ADF refer the below links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uXDt0DP9cs&ab_channel=TechBrothersIT

[Azure Data Factory V2 Pipelines for Copying Large AWS S3 Buckets to Azure Storage](https://medium.com/@brijrajsingh/azure-data-factory-v2-pipelines-for-copying-large-aws-s3-buckets-to-azure-storage-3556fa9caaf8)